# Ajax request keep returning false

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am writing a simple varification program with an ajax request:

```js
  $("#codeSbmt").click(function(){
            var $input = $("#fourDigit");
             codeCheck("codeTest.php?q=" + $input);
        })
                    function codeCheck(url) {
var xhttp;
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Here's the page it's landing to:

```js
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];



if($q === $_SESSION['pl_code']){
 $_SESSION['activated'] = true;
}else{
   echo "Incorrect code";
}
```

My dilemma is that no matter what php script is returning the else statement which is "incorrect code". I even replaced the $_SESSION with a dummy number like this:

```php
if($q === 4949){
 $_SESSION['activated'] = true;
}else{
   echo "Incorrect code";
}
```

Even then it's returning the else statement.

Comment: Try `var_dump($q);` and `var_dump($_SESSION['pl_code']);` to see what the values contain and what their types are. Since you're using the triple equals, it could just be a type mismatch, ie string vs integer.

Comment: i mean... you keep sending it the same string value `[object Object]`, of course you're going to keep getting the same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```
> var $input = $("#fourDigit");
> codeCheck("codeTest.php?q=" + $input);
> ```

You're stringifying a jQuery object (which will give you something like `"[object Object]"`).

You didn't include enough HTML (always provide a [mcve]!) but you probably meant `$input.val()`.

---

> ```
> if($q === 4949){
> ```

Data in `$_REQUEST` will be strings. Comparing it to a number with `===` won't work.